# Leak when I load custom UITableViewCells from Xib files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, instruments

I am getting leak in following code. Leak percentage @ the end of the line. Can anyone tell me what is the problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

coustomMessage *cell = (coustomMessage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"coustomMessage"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"coustomMessage" owner:self options:nil]; (93.1%)
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.nameLable.text = [self.nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; (3.4%)
cell.messageStatusLable.text = [[self.endPointCountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue]; (3.4%)

return cell;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you setted the "identifier" property in your XIB file with the same name you use in your code (with: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"coustomMessage")?

Comment: How did i miss that. Thx @meronix

Comment: @Amit: it just happens (to me too)... how do you think i get it?

Answer (score 0):

Superb! I had exactly the same issue I misspelled the identifier in the XIB and so lots of leaks as the cell we being recreated not re-used. Thanks!